# How to synchronizing several jQuery sliders?

Tags: jquery-plugins, slider

I'm using this [jquery slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/), there're 3 instances of this slider,how can I synchronize them?

js:

```
$( ".slider" ).slider();
```

html:

```
<div class="slider"></div>
...
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post code? All I can say now is to set jquery event listeners on each, then update the values of the other 2 when one is changed.

Comment: @Jared ,I've updated with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Assign a different ID to each:

```
<div class="slider" id="slider1"></div>
<div class="slider" id="slider2"></div>
<div class="slider" id="slider3"></div>
```

then on your initialization of the slider:

```
$("#slider1").slider({
   slide: function(event, ui) { 
      $("#slider2").slider("value", ui.value );
      $("#slider3").slider("value", ui.value );
   }
});

$("#slider2").slider({
   slide: function(event, ui) { 
      $("#slider1").slider("value", ui.value );
      $("#slider3").slider("value", ui.value );
   }
});

$("#slider3").slider({
   slide: function(event, ui) { 
      $("#slider1").slider("value", ui.value );
      $("#slider2").slider("value", ui.value );
   }
});
```

Comment: I assume you could generalize and use the .slider selector and only have 1 initialization, but you could run into many issues there. This answer is based on the API guide below the example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-value

Answer (score 0):

You can sync several sliders that share the same class too using .each():

```
$('.slider.sync').slider({
    min:0,
    max:100,
    slide: function(event,ui){
        $('.slider.sync').each(function(){
            $(this).slider( 'value', ui.value );    
            $(this).siblings('span.value').text( ui.value ); // print value to span.value
        });
    }
});
```

It also works if you're using the range option, just be sure to use the 'values' method instead of 'value':

```
$('.slider.sync').slider({
    range:true,
    min:0,
    max:100,
    values:[0,100],
    slide: function(event,ui){
        $('.slider.sync').each(function(){
            $(this).slider( 'values', [ ui.values[0],ui.values[1] ] );
            $(this).siblings('span.min').text( ui.values[0] ); // print min value to span.min
            $(this).siblings('span.max').text( ui.values[1] ); // print max value to span.max
        });
    }
});
```